# How can I exclude certain posts from the wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress

In the wordpress loop, how can I prevent 2 of my posts from appearing, ie exclude the:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: yes it is possible. where are u want to apply this?

Comment: An easy way would be to make a junk category, and exclude that. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/exclude-posts-from-wp_query

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
query_posts(array('post__not_in' => array(1,2)));
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

where 1 and 2 are posts that you want to exclude.